# Replace same occurrence of word with different words using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to replace 2 same words in file(app.properties) with 2 different words using sed command.
Example:

```
mysql.host=<<CHANGE_ME>>
mysql.username=testuser
mysql.port=3306
mysql.db.password=<<CHANGE_ME>>
```

required output will be

```
mysql.host=localhost
mysql.username=testuser
mysql.port=3306
mysql.db.password=password123
```

I tried below command:

`sed -e "s/<<CHANGE_ME>>/localhost/1" -e "s/<<CHANGE_ME>>/password123/2" app.properties > /home/centos/SCRIPT/io.properties_new`

However I am getting `localhost` at both the places.

Comment: Do you have control over the input?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it's not impossible, but also that you will not be able to figure out how it works once you find an answer. A better solution is to switch to a language which is more human-readable, so you can understand what it does.

```
awk 'BEGIN { split("localhost:password123", items, ":") }
    /<<CHANGE_ME>>/ { sub(/<<CHANGE_ME>>/, items[++i]) } 1' input_file >output_file
```

The `BEGIN` block creates an array `items` of replacements. The main script then increments `i` every time we perform a replacement, indexing further into `items` for the replacement string.

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible but I don't know if this is really readable for everyone.
Something like this might suite you :

```sh
sed -e '0,/<<CHANGE_ME>>/{s/<<CHANGE_ME>>/localhost/}' -e '1,/<<CHANGE_ME>>/{s/<<CHANGE_ME>>/password123/}' app.properties > /home/centos/SCRIPT/io.properties_new
```

If you have any idea to improve this, don't hesitate. I would really like to learn the best way to do this too :D

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might help:

```
sed -e '1s/<<CHANGE_ME>>/localhost/' \
    -e '4s/<<CHANGE_ME>>/password123/' \
      app.properties > /home/centos/SCRIPT/io.properties_new
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed, using a wonderfully confusing `if (first time) do x, else do y` logic:

```sh
sed '/<CHANGE_ME>/{bb;:a;s/<CHANGE_ME>/password123/;:b;x;s/E//;x;ta;s/<CHANGE_ME>/localhost/;x;s/^/E/;x}' input_file
```

Writing each command of the sed script on its own line makes it more understandable, or at least easier for me to expain it:

```
/<CHANGE_ME>/{
  bb
  :a
  s/<CHANGE_ME>/password123/
  :b
  x
  s/E//
  x
  ta
  s/<CHANGE_ME>/localhost/
  x
  s/^/E/
  x
}
```

Here's the explanation:

- `/<CHANGE_ME>/{…}` means that the stuff in `{…}` is only applied to lines matching `<CHANGE_ME>`;

1. `bb`: "`b`ranch to (go to) `:b`", in this case used to skip the first substitution command;
2. `:a`: a target for another `b`ranch or `t`est-and-branch command;
3. `s/…/…/`: you know what it does, but we skip this the first time the script is run;
4. `b`: branches to the end of the script, skipping everything (because we are giving no argument to `b`);
5. `:b`: the target of the command `bb` at 1.;
6. `x`: swap patter space (the line you're dealing with at the moment), with the hold space (a kind of variable that you can put stuff into via `x`, `h`, and `H` commands);
7. `s/E//`: tries to match and delete a `E` (just because that's the initial of my name), which fails the first time we run this, because the hold space that we've swapped earlier with the patter space was empty;
8. `x`: undos what the previous `x` did, so we're back on working with the line matching `<CHANGE_ME>`;
9. `ta`: tests if last peformed `s/…/…/` command succeeded and, if so, it goes to `:a`, otherwise it's a no-op; the first time we run the script this is a no-op, because step 6 failed;
10. `s/…/…/`: you know what it does;
11. `x`: see above
12. `s/^/E/`: inserts the `E` at the beginning of the line, so that next time we run the script substitution of step 7 succeedes, step 9 successfully branches to `:a`, step 3 is peformed for the first time, and step 4 exits the script for ever;
13. `x`: see above